# Change image dynamically in ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, oracle12c

I have created one demo application containing a single table with 5 columns. First row contains employee id along with an image. What i want is whenever i click on the table row the image corresponds to that row gets change to another image. could you please tell me how? I am using Jdeveloper12 version

### style class for image1

```
af|image.customImage
{
       background: url("../../Images/Search.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       width: 20pt;
        height: 20pt;
}
```

### Style class for second image

```
af|image.customImage
{
       background: url("../../Images/icTickActive.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       width: 20pt;
        height: 20pt;
}
```

I have created a bean class and bind the StyleClass property of image into the style variable declared on the bean class.

### Bean Class

```
public class SelectionBean {
public SelectionBean() {
}
private String imageStyle="customImageChecked";

public void setImageStyle(String imageStyle) {
    this.imageStyle = imageStyle;
}

public String getImageStyle() {
    return imageStyle;
}

public void changeImage(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) { //table selectionlistener event
   if(imageStyle.equals("customImage")) {
       setImageStyle("customImageChecked");
   }else {
    setImageStyle("customImage");   
   }
}}
```

could anyone please help me to correct my mistake???

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a partialTrigger connection between the table and the image, so the image will refresh when you do the row selection.